# Do you need to use the {} brackets when grabbing an field by the GUID

Tags: splistitem, guid

When trying to grab a field by guid, do you need to surround the guid with {}? E.g.

field["{xxx343-xx-324-xxx}"]

or

field["xxx343-xx-324-xxx"]

Comment: Which SharePoint API you are referring to?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) has 3 "Item" methods defined that take an identifier between brackets:

- item[string fieldName]
- item[int index]
- item[Guid fieldId]

You seem to be trying to use *item[Guid fieldId]*, but you are providing a string, not a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) structure, so in effect you are calling *item[string fieldName]* and thus SharePoint expects a field name, not a field id.

You should be calling your method like so:

item[new Guid("{936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8}"]

to properly form a Guid structure. With or without curly braces { } or parenthesis ( ), as the Guid [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) accepts both. Do NOT use square brackets [ ].

Comment: Thats what I was lookking for, but do I need to use item[new Guid("{xxx343-xx-324-xxx}"]?

Comment: Yes, with the new sorry. Edited my post. You can include curly braces or not, both will work.